# How to download file using objective c with webservice returns byte array

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, file-transfer

I have an iPhone application. In my login view I send the username and password to an ASP.NET webservice and the webservice  returns JSON. If the user is logged in successfully, I have another method to call from the webservice which you can see below:

```
[WebMethod]
public Byte[] GetDocument(string DocumentName)
{
    string strdocPath;
    strdocPath = "path" + DocumentName;

    FileStream objfilestream = new FileStream(strdocPath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    int len = (int)objfilestream.Length;            
    Byte[] documentcontents  = new Byte[len];
    objfilestream.Read(documentcontents,0,len);
    objfilestream.Close();

    return documentcontents;    
}
```

Now my question is: how can I call this method from my iPhone application and save it to documents directory as a `.sqlite` or `.db` file

Answer (score 0):

@Try this

```
NSOutputStream *fileOutputStream;
NSString *databasePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@",NSHomeDirectory(),@"database.sqlite"];
    fileOutputStream = nil;
    fileOutputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToFileAtPath:databasePath append:NO];
    [fileOutputStream open];


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

   int bytesWritten  = [fileOutputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
    NSLog(@" %s bytesWritten == %d  error == %@",__FUNCTION__,bytesWritten,[fileOutputStream streamError]);
}
```

Comment: but how can i call my web service forexample the service path is http.//test.com/myservice.asmx and it gets string parameter. how can i call it from ios?

Comment: string parameter means that is file downloading url for example :http://xyz.14.111.19/application/database.zip